# Convergence of a sequences of projecting point on a set of hyperplanes

Tags: linear-algebra

How to prove next statement?
Consider finite number intersecting hyperplanes in N dimensional Euclidean space and some starting point $x_0$. Point $x_i$ is obtained from point $x_{i-1}$ by projecting to some hyperplane, so $x_i = P_k(x_{i-1})$ where $P_k(\cdot)$ is orthogonal projection on hyperplane k. Given that we choose hyperplanes in some order, the sequence of point $x_0, x_1, \dots $ will converges.
Hyperplanes go though zero and total number of them is N-1, so intersection of all of them is a line.

Also,I would really appreciate if somebody can give reference to similar statement in literature.

Comment: Are you supposing that the number of hyperplanes is finite?

Comment: Yes, the number of hyperplanes is finite.

Comment: You presumably mean hyperplanes through the origin, not affine hyperplanes, because if you had two parallel hyperplanes then you could project a point back and forth between them and the sequence wouldn't converge.  Also "projecting operator" presumably means orthogonal projection.

Comment: Yes, you are right.